# Bit Manipulation AdHoc Variation

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation, time-complexity, adhoc

**Question:**

You are given two **sorted** arrays A and B **(size can vary from 1 to 10^5)**, having elements in range of **(1,10^5)**. You are also given an array C of size **Highest element in A + Highest element in B**, with all elements 0 initially. Now, we have to update C like this:

```
for i in A:
    for j in B:
        C[i+j] += 1
```

And have to find out final C.

**Time Limit:** 1sec (So Time Complexity should not be n^2)

**Example:**

```
A = [2,4]
B = [1,3]
Then C would be = [0,0,1,0,2,0,1] (assuming 1th indexed)
```

I am not sure from where I should start. I tried to think a way so that we could increase more than 1 in C at a time, But could not find it. For a moment I was thinking in this way, Assume A as binary string: "0101" and we are shifting It by elements in B, But again this is not leading anywhere too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the link of the problem?

Comment: The example does not seem good to me: no element should be greater than size of A or B. There should be either repeated elements, or just the trivial sequence from 1 to size of A...

Comment: @aka.nice I did not get you.. Why it cannot be like that?

Comment: Array A &B are of size 10^5 with elements in range (1,10^5), so no element should be bigger than A size or B size in the original problem, no?

Comment: @aka.nice aah.. sorry it was little misleading.. when I am saying they are of size 10^5, I meant there size can vary from 1 to 10^5. Repetition of elements is allowed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think of your initial arrays as a histogram, then the output is given as a convolution of the two input histograms.

You can use the fast fourier transform to perform this convolution in O(nlogn) time.

For example, in Python:

```python
import scipy.signal

def hist(X):
    """Prepare a histogram of X"""
    h = [0]*(max(X)+1)
    for x in X:
        h[x] += 1
    return h

A = [2,4]
B = [1,3]
print scipy.signal.fftconvolve(hist(A),hist(B))
```

With arrays of length 10^5, this only takes 0.05 seconds on my computer.

Comment: Aah, How could I forget about convolution. Thanks bro.. :) Can you also suggest me some library for c++ too for Convolution using FFT? Or any resources which will help me to write it to achieve same?

Comment: There is some example code under the setter's code in the [editorial for this codechef problem](https://discuss.codechef.com/questions/20550/primedst-editorial)